# How can I get correct totals in SSRS matrix?

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

The matrix below has column totals under the red line. The pivoted column group columns are highlighted in yellow to the right of the vertical red line. The columns in the white to the left are not pivoted.

**So it looks like the totals under the pivoted yellow columns are correct,**

**but the totals under the regular columns are totally wrong.**

Those are simple `=Sum(Fields!columnX.Value)` totals in a group total row.

[image]

Matrix design is as follows (wherever you see "Expr" it is simply that `Sum` multiplied by a temporarily used constant `1`, except where I deleted that from `pour_weight` for simplicity):

[image]

It appears that SSRS totals the left columns **BEFORE** pivoting the right columns, which is a total disaster.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What on Earth does that drive-by downvote mean? No comment, no attempt to answer... If you are such a smart ass (as in 'donkey'), put it writing, will you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating a 2nd dataset without detail columns and with the `Sum`s of each on the remaining columns, then using a `Lookup` function in the matrix cells to find the correct group's correct total.